# Replace string with \ char not work in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, non-ascii-characters

On my project I need to import from clipboard excel data.

But in case we have german chars like `"ä ö ü"` I need to replace:

```
clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);

clipboardText.Replace("\u252\'fc", "ü");
```

I got this error from compiler:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `@` in front of the `"` :

```
clipboardText.Replace(@"\u252'fc", "ü");
```

Or double the `\\` :

```
clipboardText.Replace("\\u252'fc", "ü");
```

Comment: I think the 2nd one has one too many slashes. This will evaluate the following two chunks and still error on the latter: (<double slash>) (\u252). Assuming his string is simple text with the characters \, u, 2, 5, and 2, then your 1st method should still work.

Comment: Many thanks, i add the @ and it works fine